Persist data after factory reset?
I have full access to AOSP code and need to have some data (integer number) persisted after factory reset.
I guess the best option would be to read/write to a file, but I don't know where to store it to be safe from factory reset?
I am also open to using other methods, like props, but I haven't found anything that would help me with this.
The data must be saved on the device (no cloud etc).

Is there a possibility to write to the /system partition?

there is and i tried it, but it gets wiped after factory reset.
i've did it via adb shell... don't know if there is any difference if an app does it or if i do it manually.

I believe the a blank file needs to be copied at compile time and made a part of the system image. Later you can use to persist write to this file?

It's going to depend on the device maker. Check all mounted partitions, and look in /sys/class/block for unmounted partitions. Ultimately you may or may not find one of the partitions that is usable. If you are building your own device talk to your OEM or chipset vendor.
